# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I´m tri to run a JUnit Test um my spring boot project i bilded like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.br.suppcomm.ocp.entity.Login;


public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Login, Long>{
...
}
```

Service:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.CompanyDAO;
import com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao;
import com.br.suppcomm.ocp.entity.Login;



@Service
public class LoginService  {

    @Autowired LoginDao loginDao; 


    @Autowired CompanyDAO companyDao;


    public void save(Login login) {

        loginDao.save(login);


    }


    public void delete(Login login) {
         loginDao.delete(login);
    }


    public Login findById(Login login) {
        return loginDao.findOne(login.getLoginId());
    }


    public Login findByEmail(Login login) {
        return loginDao.findByEmail(login.getEmail());
    }


    public Login FindByLogin(Login login) {
        return loginDao.FindByLogin(login);
    }


    public List<Login> getAll() {

        return loginDao.findAll();
    }


    public Login getUserAccessLoginPass(String login, String password) {
        return loginDao.getUserAccessLoginPass(login, password);
    }


    public void update(Login login) {
         loginDao.save(login);

    }
```

}

Test:

```
package com.example;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.br.suppcomm.ocp.service.LoginService;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest
public class OcpJpaApplicationTests {

    @Autowired LoginService loginService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {


    }    

}
```

When I ran this code did show me the folow error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
```

> Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'loginDao': No qualifying bean of type
>
> [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao] found for dependency 
>   [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as  autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations: 
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested  exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
>   qualifying bean of type [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao] found for
>   dependency  [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao]: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as  autowire candidate for this dependency.
>   Dependency annotations: 
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I dont know what happened!! Please.

Comment: What packages are your classes in?

Comment: For starters, you should let us see your main class... Your annotations are missing all over... You need a @Repository on your repository. You need to annotate correctly your test class, like this: 


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) and for a more exact answer, we need to see your main class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add @Repository your Interface

annotation , so that it can be Autowired.

```
@Repository
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Login, Long>{

}
```

It'll work that way!
Exception says that SPring is not able to find a qualifier, to Autowired something you need to sterotype it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the `classes` attribute to your `@SpringBootTest` annotation as follows:

@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })

So that it will know that it has to do component scan, etc that you've specified on your `Application` class.

Comment: Didn't work.   I put this code and in Application.class has componentScan annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Repository` annotation on LoginDao

Comment: We need a third answer for the last missing piece! Anyone volunteering..? :-)

Comment: Try using `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class}, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)` instead of `@SpringBootTest` along with `@Repository` on LoginDao

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(classes = { OcpJpaApplication.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {OcpJpaApplication.class}, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class OcpJpaApplicationTests {   ---Didn't work to

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao] found for dependency [com.br.suppcomm.ocp.dao.LoginDao]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: SpringApplicationContextLoader is depricated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this annotation to your test:

`@DataJpaTest`

This will cause the Persistence slice of you application to be initialized.